# LINQ iterate through results

Tags: linq

I am trying to read the following text file:

```
    Author
    {
    Name  xyz
    blog  www.test.com
    rating 123
    }    
   Author
    {
    Name  xyz
    blog  www.test.com
    rating 123
    }   
    Author
    {
    Name  xyz
    blog  www.test.com
    rating 123
    }   
    Author
    {
    Name  xyz
    blog  www.test.com
    rating 123
    }
```

I am using the following snippet to fetch my author record:

```
  public static IEnumerable<string> GetAuthors(string path, string startfrom, string endto)
        {
            return File.ReadLines(path)
                .SkipWhile(line => line != startfrom)
                .TakeWhile(line => line != endto);
        }



 public static void DoSomethingWithAuthors(string fileName)
        {
            var result = GetAuthors(fileName, "AUTHOR", "}").ToList();
         }
```

The above only returns me one Author Details.  Could someone kindly show me how to fetch all authors in one go so I could popluate to an object.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: LINQ isn't meant for parsing. You should parse the file some other way.

Comment: I don't understand you have code that reads one author and then you ask why it reads just one.  If you want to read more than one you have to use a loop.  loops are not evil -- they are just loops.  you need a loop, use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rarely suggest that, but if the file structure is that predicatable you might even use regex to get your author details. As the objects you want to initialize are not complex, you can match the `Author` bit and take the values from regex match groups.

the regex to match the authors would be something like this:

```
Author\s*{\s*Name\s+(.*?)\s+blog\s+(.*?)\s+rating\s+(.*?)\s*}
```

Your values would be in the group 1,2 and 3.

**EDIT:**

If it doesn't make a difference for you, you can use the ReadToEnd() method and then you can parse the whole file content as a string:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.100).aspx

As for the regex solution - check this out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx

An adapted version - it might need tweaking but in general it should work:

```
string text = [yourInputFileAsString]
      string pat = @"Author\s*{\s*Name\s+(.*?)\s+blog\s+(.*?)\s+rating\s+(.*?)\s*}";

      Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

      Match m = r.Match(text);

      var authors = new List<Author>();
      while (m.Success) 
      {
         var name = m.Groups[1].Value;
         var blog = m.Groups[2].Value;
         var rating = m.Groups[3].Value;
         var author = new Author(name, blog, rating);
         authors.Add(author);

         m = m.NextMatch();
      }
```

Comment: well the problem right now is im unable to get a collection of authors. I am only able to get one author node if I dont use the takeline. I am wondering How i could fetch a list of authors and then populate the values. Can you show me a detail example of how to accomplish this with regex, appreciate it!!!

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you!! Just one thing, Lets say, if the values in the fileds could be blank,)(I.E field description will be there but no value) and in that case the regex fetches the next line. Also I have other fields in this node, but im only interested in fetching a few, so in the case if any field is blank I need to break and go to the next value in the regex path. I dont have much experience with reges's, do you know how I could handle that

Comment: @user721 - I would suggest raising this as a separate regex question - then you can provide us with some more examples of how your input file looks like. A quick optimization that would stop the regex from falling through to next Author object would be this: `"Author\s*{\s*Name\s*([^}]*?)\s+blog\s*([^}]*?)\s+rating\s*([^}]*?)\s*}"`. As I don't know where the other elements could appear but you can make things optional in regex- so do raise it separately. And a friendly reminder - if the answer helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to stop at the first `}` it runs into.

Remove the `.TakeWhile(line => line != endto)` bit and it should work for you.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what its doing, should i use ReadAllLines instead or have a foreach loop or something?

Comment: I agree with @Kendall that you shouldn't really be using LINQ to do parsing. Your file format is very close to JSON, so maybe you could just do that and save yourself some grief.  You __could__ use `ReadAllLines` and it should work as I described in my answer.